# How to make a task schedule that would only run a program at logon

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation, windows-task-scheduler

I have a project that currently executes a program to install drivers/programs during OOBE. This is possible because my install is automated by putting unattend.xml in the Panther folder. The program runs from SetupComplete.cmd, but this leads to issues as its run by SYSTEM and not Administrator. This makes some programs not install correctly. I want to know if its possible to make a task that only runs once the user is at the Desktop for the first time and run my program which is located at:
`C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\PortableDriver.exe --install`
For example: WinPE is done, Windows Initializes and auto does OOBE, User logs onto account, once they reach the desktop they see the driver wizard.
Note: this must be done only once.

Comment: you could create a script that writes another script to the user's startup folder, and make it delete itself at the very end.